# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_85_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28) on MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to fit a neural network composed of dense layers on MNIST.

I am getting

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_85_input to have 4 
dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)
```

Here is my code and the corresponding output:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu", input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_20"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_85 (Dense)             (None, 28, 28, 100)       200       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_86 (Dense)             (None, 28, 28, 300)       30300     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_87 (Dense)             (None, 28, 28, 100)       30100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_88 (Dense)             (None, 28, 28, 10)        1010      
=================================================================
Total params: 61,610
Trainable params: 61,610
Non-trainable params: 0

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.0),
                     metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-c38680d35ec3> in <module>
      1 new_model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.0),
      2                      metrics=["accuracy"])
----> 3 history = new_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    233           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    234           workers=workers,
--> 235           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    236 
    237       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    591         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    592         workers=workers,
--> 593         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    594     val_adapter = None
    595     if validation_data:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    644     standardize_function = None
    645     x, y, sample_weights = standardize(
--> 646         x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
    647   elif adapter_cls is data_adapter.ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter:
    648     standardize_function = standardize

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2381         is_dataset=is_dataset,
   2382         class_weight=class_weight,
-> 2383         batch_size=batch_size)
   2384 
   2385   def _standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly, dict_inputs,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly, dict_inputs, is_dataset, class_weight, batch_size)
   2408           feed_input_shapes,
   2409           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
-> 2410           exception_prefix='input')
   2411 
   2412     # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    571                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    572                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 573                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    574         if not check_batch_axis:
    575           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_85_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)
```

I also tried putting `input_shape=(28, 28)` on the first Dense layer, but then I get the following error:

```
Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/10
   32/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 19:24

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-c38680d35ec3> in <module>
      1 new_model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.0),
      2                      metrics=["accuracy"])
----> 3 history = new_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    341                 training_context=training_context,
--> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
    343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    344 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    613       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    614       initializers = []
--> 615       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    616     finally:
    617       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    495     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    496         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 497             *args, **kwds))
    498 
    499     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2387       args, kwargs = None, None
   2388     with self._lock:
-> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2390     return graph_function
   2391 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2701 
   2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2591             arg_names=arg_names,
   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2594         self._function_attributes,
   2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    976                                           converted_func)
    977 
--> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    979 
    980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    437         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    441 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     83     args = _prepare_feed_values(model, input_iterator, mode, strategy)
     84     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 85         per_replica_function, args=args)
     86     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     87     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    761       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    762                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 763       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    764 
    765   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1817       kwargs = {}
   1818     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1819       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1820 
   1821   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2162         self._container_strategy(),
   2163         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2164       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2165 
   2166   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, standalone)
    431       y,
    432       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 433       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    434 
    435   if reset_metrics:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    310           sample_weights=sample_weights,
    311           training=True,
--> 312           output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
    313   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    314     outs = [outs]

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _process_single_batch(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    251               output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics,
    252               sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 253               training=training))
    254       if total_loss is None:
    255         raise ValueError('The model cannot be run '

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    165 
    166         if hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
--> 167           per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
    168           weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    169               per_sample_losses,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
    219       y_pred, y_true = tf_losses_util.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
    220           y_pred, y_true)
--> 221     return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    222 
    223   def get_config(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py in sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits, axis)
    976 def sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
    977   return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
--> 978       y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    979 
    980 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in sparse_categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits, axis)
   4571     with get_graph().as_default():
   4572       res = nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
-> 4573           labels=target, logits=output)
   4574   else:
   4575     res = nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels, logits, name)
   3535   """
   3536   return sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
-> 3537       labels=labels, logits=logits, name=name)
   3538 
   3539 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(_sentinel, labels, logits, name)
   3451                        "should equal the shape of logits except for the last "
   3452                        "dimension (received %s)." % (labels_static_shape,
-> 3453                                                      logits.get_shape()))
   3454     # Check if no reshapes are required.
   3455     if logits.get_shape().ndims == 2:

ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (32, 1)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (32, 28, 10)).
```

I don't know what's wrong here since the [TensorFlow Datasets MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/mnist) specification says the image is of shape `(28, 28, 1)`.

What's going on here? How do I fix it?

Comment: @Frightera not sure this is the issue here; in the [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) it works OK with `input_shape=(28, 28)`.

Comment: @desertnaut I saw the model wrong thanks, but in tutorial it is flattened before `Dense()`.

Comment: @Frightera indeed, but I guess this should not be an issue...?

Comment: I think that `Dense()` is expecting flattened feature vector. Author is trying to pass 28x28 instead of 784x1.

Comment: @Frightera when I add a `Flatten` layer before the Dense layer, it works. Why is that so?